# Vue fade transition on timeout function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, transition

I am using a `setTimeout` function to update an existing `{{title}}` text. I understand the normal method to add a fade transition would be to wrap it around `{{title}}` like:

`<transition name="fade">
   {{title}}
 </transition>`

However, as the title is being updated inside the `cycle` function, how do I add a fade transition?

```
created: function created() {
  var self = this

      setTimeout(function cycle() {

        self.title = self.posts[self.currentIndex++].title

        self.currentIndex %= self.posts.length

        setTimeout(cycle, 3000)
      }, 5000)

},
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to tell from your code, but my best guess is that you didn't implement the CSS to actually create the transition. For example something like this (from docs):

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

If you add the CSS it should work exactly as you describe. More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Also, don't you mean this?

```
methods: {
    updateTitle() {
        this.title = this.posts[this.currentIndex++].title
        this.currentIndex %= this.posts.length
    }
},
created() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.updateTitle()
    setInterval(() => {
        this.updateTitle()
    }, 3000)
  }, 5000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually just got it working by adding a key and fade type: `<transition name="fade" mode="out-in"><p class="mb-0" :key="currentIndex">{{text}}</p></transition>` Thanks!